# CSURF token with NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, token

However, if I discover that someone has access to my JWT token and data via JWTIo, I attempt to secure the token. I came up with a workaround utilizing Csurf, which I configured in nestjs, but it shows an invalid Csurf and csurf token mismatch.

```
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import * as csurf from 'csurf';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { envConfig } from '../config/env.config';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// bootstrap...
async function bootstrap() {
  const port = envConfig.port;

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: {
      origin: true,
      methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
      exposedHeaders: ['Location'],
      allowedHeaders: [
        "Content-Type",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN",
        "access-control-allow-methods",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "access-control-allow-credentials",
        "access-control-allow-headers",
      ],
      preflightContinue: false,
      credentials: true,
    },
    bodyParser: false,
    logger: ['warn', 'error', 'debug'],
    bufferLogs: true
  });

  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(csurf({ cookie: { sameSite: true } }));

  app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    const token = req.csrfToken();
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
    res.locals.csrfToken = token;

    next();
  });

  await app.listen(port);
}

bootstrap();
```